# Axis 1.2.1 WSDD tutorial

Tags: axis

Have been googling for a while, but I don't find any page which explains CLEARLY what is each element from the [WSDD](https://axis.apache.org/axis/java/reference.html#Deployment_WSDD_Reference) file. I want to know what does the transport element do exactly (on the server side), but I become always a really small description.

Can anyone explain it a little bit, or tell me from a tutorial a bit more extended?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the [Axis WSDD Referenz](http://www.oio.de/axis-wsdd/) to be quite useful while working with Axis 1.3.

I am not sure if all tags are presented or if the information is updated for newer Axis versions. Some explanations are a little too succinct, but enough to serve as a starting point.

Comment: Thanks! Have seen that before, it is helpful to get an idea of what is each element, but it doesn't get really much into the subject. But thanks anyway :-)